# Quadratic functions - using substitution

Tags: quadratics

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2+2bx+c=0$, find the quadratic equation with the roots $\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}$ using transformation method or by substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that $\alpha+\beta=-\frac{2b}{a}$ and  $\alpha\beta=-\frac{c}{a}$. Hence
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha\beta}=\frac{-2b/a}{c/a}=-\frac{2b}{c}$$
which implies that
$$S:=\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}+\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}=-\frac{2b}{a}-\frac{2b}{c}.$$
Are you able to find the product
$$P:=\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\left(\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}\right)=\alpha\beta
+\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{\alpha\beta}-2+\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}?$$
Then the quadratic equation that you are looking for is
$x^2-Sx+P=0$.

Comment: is there a special way to get the answer like by using a substitution etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x+\dfrac1x$  $$\implies x^2+(-y)x+1=0\  \ \ \  (1)$$

We already have $$ax^2+bx+c=0\  \ \ \ (2)$$

Solve the simultaneous equations  $(1),(2)$ for $x^2,x$

and use $$x^2=(x)^2$$ to eliminate $x$

Comment: is there another special way to get the answer like using a substitution

Comment: Sir, I'm observing your algebra skills on this site, that is awesome, so I request you, could you please suggest me Algebra book, or other resources, so that I can try reaching your standards, please. I'm preparing for JEE/KVPY (hope you know JEE and KVPY). Please reply.

Comment: @mnulb, See https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp  ,  https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall ,     Elementary Number Theory  by David Burton ,   Elementary Number Theory: Kenneth H. Rosen

Answer (score 0):

If we denote $S=p+q$ and $P=pq$ then $p,q$ are the roots of the quadratic $X^2-Sx +P=0$. We have $\alpha+\beta=-2b/a$ and $\alpha\beta=c/a$. Let's compute

$$\alpha+{1\over\alpha}+\beta+{1\over \beta}=\alpha+\beta+{\alpha+\beta\over \alpha\beta}=-2\left({b\over a}+{b\over c}\right)$$

$$\left(\alpha+{1\over\alpha}\right)\left(\beta+{1\over \beta}\right)=\alpha\beta+{\alpha^2+\beta^2\over \alpha\beta}+{1\over\alpha\beta}$$

On top we can check that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta$. We finish by substituting

Comment: is there another special way to find the answer like using a substitution